# Ces « bulles » que l'on boit : étendue du sens, nature et depuis quand ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, origine-ou-raison, alimentation

> Les bulles anglaises sont vinifiées comme en Champagne. (Karyne
>   Duplessis Piché, [Vendanges: du jamais vu en Angleterre](https://www.lapresse.ca/vins/actualites/201810/26/01-5201790-vendanges-du-jamais-vu-en-angleterre.php), La
>   Presse)

Au Wiktionnaire on indique que le mot [*bulles*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bulle) au pluriel peut-être employé pour désigner le [*champagne*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/champagne/1). Entendre quelqu'un dire « j'aime les bulles » ne me surprend pas et je comprends en contexte qu'on parle de *vins mousseux*. Le sens usuel pour le « globule d'air » [remonte](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bulles) au 16<sup>e</sup>.

---

- L'emploi de *bulles* au pluriel désigne-t-il surtout le vin de
  Champagne et/ou tous les vins mousseux ; peut-on expliquer/illustrer ?
- L'emploi de bulles est-il courant, spécialisé,
  appartient-il à un registre particulier, s'agit-il d'un emploi par ellipse ou métonymie ou autrement ; est-ce courant avec la référence à une origine (*anglaises* dans l'exemple) ou avec autre chose qu'il serait pertinent de mentionner ?
- Depuis quand l'emploie-t-on ?

Comment: Aux temps estudiantins et donc peu fortunés... d'aCOSwt et ses potes... la *bulle* était *surtout* plus associée au 0 aussi fatidique que minable qu'on s'était pris au précédent DS... ;-) On notera d'ailleurs curieusement qu'en ce genre d'occasion ou on s'était donc bien *planté, gaufré, banané...* on disait d'ailleurs avoir *vendangé*... comme quoi... il y avait peut-être aussi une fatalité de rapport avec le vin... ;-)

Comment: En bref de ci-dessus, comme tu l'as noté dans ta question, la polyvocité de *bulle* est telle, (en plus ce mot a été emprunté au latin deux fois) que ce qu'il désigne *surtout* dépendra du contexte.

Comment: Enfin, et pour répondre à la seconde question, je dirais que, pour bulle -> champagne, il s'agit plus d'une **synecdoque** que d'une métonymie.

Comment: Les bulles, une mousse, ou le volant… c'est pas comme si le cas des bulles était unique !

Comment: «Certains spécialistes voient une distinction nette entre synecdoques et métonymies. D’autres estiment qu’elles font partie d’un même ensemble. Cette deuxième opinion semble raisonnable, car on sent que c’est le même esprit qui se manifeste» —Les figures de style, *Henri SUHAMY*, Coll. *que sais-je*, PUF

Comment: @Montéedelait : *"raisonnable car on sent que"* Hmmm!... HaboN? ;-) Et puis Menfin... et même quoi! Quand bien même ce serait... si les fantaisies de style ne peuvent même plus s'offrir de fantaisies dénominatives... pffff... tout fout vraiment l'camp! ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt La citation est bien entendu plus longue, mais elle ne tiendrait pas dans un seul commentaire. Et il y a aussi bien sûr des droits d'auteur à respecter. C'est une simple indication si vous en êtes curieux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Que sont les bulles, lorsqu’elles ne sont pas des bulles au sens propres, c’est à dire des globules sphérique de gaz, mais autre chose via métonymie, synecdoque, métaphore ou autre figure de style ?

---

#### De la bande dessinée ?

Tout à fait ! Les bulles, ou phylactères, qui accompagnent presque toutes les bandes dessinées, sont si typiques de ce genre de narration que l’on peut facilement trouver quelques expressions liées à la bédé qui n’ont pas ressenti le besoin de la nommer, les bulles remplissant convenablement cette tâche. Par exemple :

- En 1992 commence à Saint-Malo le festival [**Quai des bulles**](http://www.quaidesbulles.com/) qui deviendra de nos jours le deuxième plus important festival de bande dessinée de France par sa fréquentation. Le nom est un clin d’œil en forme de paronomase implicite au roman [*Le Quai des brumes*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Quai_des_brumes_(roman)) de Pierre Mac Orlan, dont on tira aussi un film en 1938.
- Quand le site web et réseau social Babelio propose un palmarès de la « [**littérature en bulles**](https://www.babelio.com/liste/2178/La-litterature-en-bulles-) », il classe les meilleures adaptations d’œuvres littéraires en bande dessinée.
- Quatre bédéistes québécois créent un atelier de travail : [**La Shop à Bulles**](https://www.facebook.com/pg/shopabulles/events/?ref=page_internal).
- Un prix littéraire pour une œuvre en bande dessinée, ouverts aux jeunes de 11 à 18 ans : le prix [**Bulles de Cristal**](https://www.prixbullesdecristal.com/).

---

#### Du savon ?

Eh oui ! Au Québec, le Quai des bulles n’a plus à voir avec la bédé. Il s’agit plutôt d’une [savonnerie](https://www.quaidesbulles.ca/) à Kamouraska.

L’appelation n’est pas complètement dénuée de sens : les bulles de savon font partie de notre enfance à tous, et quel enfant n’est pas fasciné par ces entités irisées, si parfaitement sphériques, légères au point de réagir aux moindres moindres mouvements de l’air, mais si fugaces qu’on ne peut les étudier que sur le vif ?

D’ailleurs, les bulles économiques ([bulles spéculatives](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8362567) ou [bulles immobilières](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8374171)) utilisent cette fragilité et cette tendance à l’éclatement pour qualifier des événements économiques où les valeurs de ventes peuvent s’anéantir en un instant.

---

#### Et du vin mousseux, bien sûr, puisque c’était là la question

Qu’en est-il du vin en général en France et en français ? Henri Suhamy, dans son *Que sais-je ?* sur les figures de style, en donne un aperçu réaliste et commente plus avant :

> [...] *verre, bouteille, rouge, cep, réserve, pampre, Bacchus, gamay, pays, soleil, terroir, coteau,* etc., [...] dans une phrase, dans une formule publicitaire, peuvent prendre la place du mot *vin*. [...] Autres exemples :
>
> - Il a des villages et des appellations plein sa cave, mais il ne vous servira que du onze degrés.
> - Dégustez-moi ce bouquet, c’est du propriétaire, pas du négociant.
>
> [...] D’autre part, l’exemple typiquement français du mot *vin* scintillant de mille reflets métonymiques révèle l’aspect ethnologique de la question : on parle à des initiés en leur fournissant sur l’objet du discours des précisions très fines qui remplacent le terme générique.

Il se conçoit donc que l’on ait pu voir *bulles* remplacer *vin mousseux*, et ce même si l’on avait déjà substantivé *mousseux* pour la même chose. Mais peut-être aussi cette première appelation de *mousseux* était-elle trop entachée déjà, au Québec du moins, d’une notion d’infériorité, puisque le terme brisait en fait la catégorie des vins mousseux en deux parties, le noble champagne et le moindre mousseux. En définissant ***les bulles***, on redonnait en quelque sorte une certaine noblesse aux *autres* vins mousseux, on les réhabilitait.

<sup>(Qui plus est, une autre [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33143/13100) indique qu’une mousse abondante serait plutôt un signe de mauvaise qualité pour un vin mousseux. Peut-être les bulles rachètent-elles en plus un choix de mot malheureux ?)</sup>

Car en effet, les mousseux en général et non seulement les champagnes peuvent être désignés par ***bulles***. Il en va ainsi de l’exemple cité dans la question, les bulles *« vinifiées comme en Champagne »* ne sont assurément pas du vin de Champagne, et on ne prendrait pas le temps d’indiquer une vinification à la champenoise si cette caractéristique était obligatoire aux bulles.

D’autres sources confirment d’ailleurs cette affirmation, le champagne n’a pas l’exclusivité de la dénomination :

- [Bulles Whisky & cie](http://www.bulleswhisky.com/edition/quebec), un *« événement grand public rassemblant exclusivement les meilleures **bulles**, spiritueux et cocktails »* (il est ici question des vins mousseux en général).

---

#### Et les médias ?

Je relève quelques exemples à partir de Google News en cette fin de décembre 2018, qui donnera un aperçu des possibilités de désignations métonymiques de la **bulle** et qui montrera empiriquement qu’elles sont bien toutes vivantes aujourd’hui :

> - **Des bulles** à déposer sous le sapin de Noël ! (section *BD - Idées de cadeaux*)
>     <sub>–Le progrès.fr, 21 décembre 2018</sub>
> - Champagne bio: **les bulles** les plus rares
>     <sub>–Bilan.ch, 21 décembre 2018</sub>
> - Causons **bulles** : La success-story du crémant !
>     <sub>[un regard sur les vins mousseux vinifiées en dehors de la Champagne, mais selon la méthode traditionnelle]</sub>
>     <sub>–Le Parisien + Les Grappes, 21 décembre 2018</sub>
> - Pourquoi **les bulles** nous rendent pompette?
>     <sub>–Protégez-vous.ca, 13 décembre 2018</sub>
> - 2018 en revue : avril et **la bulle du bitcoin**
>     <sub>[bulle spéculative]</sub>
>     <sub>–TheConversation.com, 19 décembre 2018</sub>
> - Bd Boum : 35e clap de **bulles**
>     <sub>[à propos de la 35<sup>e</sup> édition du Festival bd Boum de Blois]</sub>
>     <sub>–LaNouvelleRépublique.fr, 23 novembre 2018</sub>
> - Champagnes Pol Roger : **des bulles** adoubées par la reine Elizabeth
>     <sub>–LeMonde.fr, 17 décembre 2018</sub>

Le choix ci-dessus n’est pas entièrement représentatif. Les bulles de vins mousseux dominent plus clairement qu’ici, mais pas outrageusement non plus. Chacun pourra de toute manière recréer l’expérience dans le futur, avec de nouveaux articles et de nouvelles bulles comme résultat.

Je termine en citant de nouveau Henri Suhamy, dans le même ouvrage que précédemment, qui semble nous indiquer que la métonymie et la trope en général possèdent une valeur qui, tout en échappant le plus souvent à notre conscient, assurera probablement la pérénnité dans la langue de ces pourtant si fragiles bulles.

> Le caractère allusif et concentré de la plupart des tropes permet de formuler une loi : le principe d’économie et de connivence, grâce auquel l’auteur trouve avec son récepteur un point de contact ténu et discret, mais par où passe, avec la rapidité d’un flux électrique, un message complexe, riche d’informations emmagasinées.

Comment: Merci ! Une réponse sous forme de cadeau inattendu après une récompense ! Vos contributions sont multiples et la réponse, vraiment excellente. De Joyeuses Fêtes !

Comment: Je *plussoye* toutes les propositions du commentaire ci-dessus avec autant de joie que je vous en souhaite, @Saint-Jacques et Mdl, en ce jour de Noël.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Étant affirmé que **LA** réponse intéressante ici est bien celle de *Montée_de_lait*. La valeur de ce qui suit n'est que comptable et donc pas supérieure à celle d'une simple note de bas de page.</sub>

<sub>Dans les conditions et avec les réserves exposées ailleurs (je ne sais plus où)</sub>

Pour ce qui est de la *bulle*

```
1  : *rescrit* : 35
2  : *décrétale* : 30
3  : *phlyctène* : 15
4  : *phylactère* : 12
   : *cloque* : 12
   : *décret* : 12
7  : *globule* : 11
   : *vésicule* : 11
9  : *ampoule* : 9
10 : *bref* : 8
   : *mandement* : 8
   : *mousse* : 8
```

Avec toutes les réserves que m'avait d'abord suggéré l'emploi de *surtout* par *Saint_Jacques*, on pourrait donc dire que *bulle* a *surtout* le sens de *rescrit*.
On notera, mais au dixième rang seulement... le sens de *mousse*. Autant dire qu'on est très loin de signifier *surtout* le champagne.

Inversement (et, IMHO très curieusement), on trouverait pour Champagne, *mousseux* au tout premier rang des sens.

On pourrait alors dire que, par le truchement de la *mousse*, Ce serait plus le champagne qui est *surtout* lié à la bulle que la bulle ne l'est au champagne.

Très curieusement, selon moi, dans la mesure où... les auteurs les plus qualifiés nous informent que, si on veut tenir Dom Pérignon pour l'inventeur de la méthode... tout indique que son vin était en fait on ne peut plus calme et que les bulles, les maîtres de la mousse... c'est plus du... mauvais ;-) côté de la Manche qu'il faille les chercher...

<sub>Pour au passage suggérer ce lien vers une véritable encyclopédie aussi savante qu'autorisée d'accès libre et gratuit (le cumul est assez rare pour être remarqué) : http://maisons-champagne.com/fr/encyclopedies/histoire-du-champagne/ qui consacre toute sa première partie à l'histoire.</sub>

À votre bonne santé et encore une fois, joyeuses fêtes!

Comment: Peut-être qu’en effet *mousseux* était-il un terme trop intense, surtout si une mousse trop intense et persistante est un mauvais signe pour la qualité. Et même alors, si la qualité est basse, on demeure encore loin du collet de mousse d’une bière. Les bulles rachèteraient-elles aussi un choix de mot malheureux?

Comment: @Montéedelait : Les bulles rachèteraient un choix de mot malheureux ? C'est assurément une bonne hypothèse ça! Si on me tolère ici la *synecdoque* ;-) Il s'agirait alors d'une synecdoque dite *particularisante*. Or l'objet premier des synecdoques particularisantes est : pittoresque. Et là, oui, 100x oui! la bulle est sacrément plus pittoresque que la mousse.